# Best way to query Sqlite DB in Win32 C

Tags: c++, sqlite, winapi

I added the SQLite3 source to my project and compiled it. My file size is huge (~400KB).
I need my file to be as small as possible. What is the best way to do SQLite queries in C++ ?
When i say best i mean the *smallest* possible file size. Any other light weight SQLite libs for C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From sqlite about page

> If optional features are omitted, the size of the SQLite library can
>   be reduced below 300KiB

I guess it will be hard to go lower, and I don't think there are alternative implementations doing less
400 KB is a lot but SQlite do a lot too. Even a small database will be more than 50M. You may go lower dynamically linking with some Microsoft ADO but with many potential install or security problems (and no sqlite file support).
 My final words 400K is a lot. But for today 400K is pretty small. Many homepage are more than 1M and that's even more crazy.

Comment: I see. Thought this might of been the case.

Comment: OK, so i omitted optional features and packed my PE using UPX. File size is now 220kb. I can live with that. :D